# How to get all the Fibonacci elements in an array in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, arrays

How to store the Fibonacci series of a number in an array in Remix IDE ?

Comment: You want an example to compute them right ?

Comment: Yes thats right !

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you are looking for : it computes the fibonacci sequence up to `Fib(n)` and returns an array with all the elements from 0 to n :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Fibonacci {

    function fibonacci(uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256[] memory) {
        require(n > 1, "n must be > 1");

        uint256[] memory sequence = new uint256[](n + 1);

        // Fib(0) = 0
        sequence[0] = 0;

        // Fib(1) = 1
        sequence[1] = 1;

        // Fib(n) = Fib(n - 1) + Fib(n - 2)
        for (uint256 i = 2; i < sequence.length; i++) {
            sequence[i] = sequence[i - 1] + sequence[i - 2];
        }

        return sequence;
    }
}
```

There are other ways to compute it, but this one is the simplest. I wouldn't recommend the recursive approach due to strict limitation on the EVM stack depths.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes got it...Thank you so much ! :)